# MySQL wildcard query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm relatively new with SQL and I ran into a problem/question while doing some practice problems.

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weather-observation-station-8

Here's the query I used with MySQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE CITY LIKE '[aeiou]%[aeiou]'
```

I'm confused why this doesn't work. Here's my thinking for the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY
```

^ make sure each city returned isn't repeated

```
FROM STATION
```

^ from the STATION table

```
WHERE CITY LIKE '[aeiou]%[aeiou]'
```

^ CITY names that are selected can have the first letter begin with [aeiou], have anything in between, and end with [aeiou].

Any help or advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using regex, you can use `regexp` or `RLIKE` in place of `LIKE`. The other thing you need to do is put `^` to denote the first character, `$` to denote the last character, and `.*` for wildcard. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/5903421) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22759143/5903421):

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY
FROM STATION
WHERE CITY RLIKE '^[aeiou].*[aeiou]$'
```

Answer (score 0):

The like operator has only 2 wildcard characters: % and _, it does not handle the bracket syntax. You need regular expressions for that, and you can use the [rlike](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) operator for that. But in regular expressions you need to use `.` instead of `_` and `.*` instead of `%`.